# приписать число к числу python

Tags: python

мои попытки :

```
k = int(input())
k1 = k
m = (str(k))


m1 = m + str(k)
print(type(int(m1)))
while int(m1) %7 != 0:
    m1 = str(m1) + str(m1)
    if int(m1) % 7 == 0:
        break
print(m1)
```

нужно приписывать вводимое число к числу пока оно не станет нацело делится на 7

Comment: @entithat буквально , были числа 1 и 1 стали 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот моё решение:

```
number = [input()]

while int("".join(number)) % 7 != 0:
    number += number[0]
print("".join(number))
```

Comment: данное решение работает в бесконечном цикле без вывода number

Comment: @ДамирНабиуллин можно пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: @ДамирНабиуллин ну страховка от бесконечного цикла напрашивается... скажем, `while numer % 7 != 0 and number < very_big_num:`

Comment: @Danis ввод 1 и вывод 111111

Comment: @Danis, в вашем примере число дополняется первой цифрой изначального числа, а в задаче, как я понял, надо дополнять самими числом, т.е. на `123` ваш алгоритм выдаст `1231111`, а должен выдать `123123`

Answer (score 2):

а если так?

```
text = input()

number = int(text)

while number % 7 != 0:
    number = number * 10**len(text) + int(text)

print(number)
```

ну или так:

```
text = input()

number = text

while int(number) % 7 != 0:
    number += text

print(number)
```

Comment: да этот вариант тоже является верным

Comment: @Дамир Набиуллин, кинул и второй вариант :)